# how to link 2 table to show some specific field in each table on datagrindview using oledbcommands in visual studio c# and ms access 2016 as database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

hi Im using a Visual Studio Express 2012 c# and trying to link 2 table on 1 datagrindview here is the code im with but it seems to not working

```
 private void SearchText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            String sql = "SELECT [StockID],[ProductName],[Category],[Price],[sum(Quantity)],[sum(TotalPrice)] from Stock,Config where Stock.ConfigID=Config.ConfigID and ProductName like '" + SearchText.Text + "%' group by StockID,ProductName,Price,Category having sum(quantity > 0) order by ProductName";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            while (rdr.Read() == true)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3], rdr[4], rdr[5]);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Care to explain what is not working?

Comment: @Steve i really dont have any idea since when i try to type a letter on that text box its always stop working and i dont know what is the problem

Comment: But if you run this query in MS-Access trying to simulate the input did you get any result?

Comment: It did run but when i tried to put something on the searchtext it shows that the program is stop working so no i didnt get result on it thats why its really hard to look for what error this code is causing